# Sprout "Javascript Player API", throws "Uncaught Can not find video iframe" errror on wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue, I have a sprout video embedded in iframe, in a slick slider, and I have set this iframe to be draggable.

There is a div overlay(.iframe-overlay), that can be swipe and click. It is working fine on JSfiddle, but somehow it throws an "Uncaught Can not find video iframe" error on wordpress webiste.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/markbanong/9myn6akd/27/

Site: https://getgoally.com/ (on the "What Parents Are Saying..." section)

Below is my code

html:

```
<div class="parents-saying template-row row-margin-top">
    <div class="container">
                <h2>What Parents Are Saying...</h2>
        <div class="slider-grandparent-container element-margin-top">
            <div class="slider-parent-container">
                <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/119fd4ba181fe5cc98/858cee23708a3b72" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="119fd4ba181fe5cc98/858cee23708a3b72"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/ea90d3b01a10e2cb63/8cd05d2e6c368787" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="ea90d3b01a10e2cb63/8cd05d2e6c368787"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/7990d2b61a1ae3c0f0/aeb336123490329c" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="7990d2b61a1ae3c0f0/aeb336123490329c"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/d390d2b61a1ae3c25a/872e74b9a3a9ea24" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="d390d2b61a1ae3c25a/872e74b9a3a9ea24"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/1190d3b01a10e2c498/d983b9381d41e3bc" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="1190d3b01a10e2c498/d983b9381d41e3bc"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe allow="autoplay" class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/0690d2b51f1be2c58f/bd697fcb0fcb2c64" ?playertheme="dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" data-sprout-id="0690d2b51f1be2c58f/bd697fcb0fcb2c64"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
/**
 * Initializes and manages a Slick slider with video playback functionality.
 * Videos are played when clicking on an iframe overlay, and the script 
 * handles both original and cloned slider items.
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isDragging = false;
  var clickStartX;

  /**
   * Initializes the Slick slider with specified settings.
   */
  $('.parents-saying .slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow: "<img class='a-left slider-arrow slick-prev' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-left-arrow.webp'>",
    nextArrow: "<img class='a-right slider-arrow slick-next' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-right-arrow.webp'>",
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
      }
    }]
  });

  /**
   * Attaches event handlers to detect dragging on the slider.
   * This helps differentiate between drag and click events.
   */
  $('.parents-saying .slider')
    .on('mousedown', function(e) {
      isDragging = false;
      clickStartX = e.pageX;
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e) {
      if (Math.abs(e.pageX - clickStartX) > 5) {
        isDragging = true;
      }
    })
    .on('mouseup', function() {
      isDragging = false;
    });

  /**
   * Global click event listener for overlay elements.
   * This listener ensures that the click event on overlays triggers
   * video playback, regardless of whether the element is original or cloned.
   */
  $(document).on('click', '.parents-saying .slider__item .iframe-overlay', function(e) {
    if (!isDragging && $(e.target).closest('.slick-slide').hasClass('slick-active')) {
      playVideo($(this));
    }
  });

  /**
   * Plays the video associated with the clicked overlay.
   * @param {jQuery Object} item - The clicked overlay jQuery object.
   */
  function playVideo(item) {
    const sproutId = item.attr('data-sprout-id');
    console.log('SPROUT ID: ', sproutId);
    const player = new SV.Player({
      videoId: sproutId
    });
    player.play();
  }
});
```

Also I have added, the sprout javascript player api, in the header as per [documentation](https://sproutvideo.com/help/articles/27-javascript_player_api).

[image]